# How to get mouse-wheel scrolling working with Synergy?

Tags: synergy

I have set-up Synergy with an OSX server and a Ubuntu host. It's working nicely, except that the mouse wheel doesn't work in Linux. I used to xev command to verify that no input at all is registered when operating the mouse wheel.

I have found various bug reports about this problem, dating back from 2009, but no solution.

I also found a few blog posts where source-code patches can be downloaded. But when I tried to build the code I got errors about a missing i386 directory. (I fear that trying to build the project myself will lead to many hours of frustration..)

Does anyone know where I can download a OSX build with the applied patches?

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer [here](https://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=28#c17)

> Fix for every installation so far -- I see mostly people using linux
>   as the client so in this scenario I'm using Windows 7 as the server
>   and fedora 12 as the client.
>
> On the client:
>
> ```
> tail -f /var/log/messages
> ```
>
> now scroll as slow as possible and take note of the errors streaming
>   in.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Feb  1 18:32:45 localhost Synergy+ 1.3.4:
> 2010-02-01T18:32:45 WARNING:
> Wheel scroll delta (28) smaller than threshold (120)#012#011CXWindowsScreen.cpp,858
> ```
>
> This is pretty self-explanatory. Take note of the delta. For this
>   setup, when I scroll slow, I get 28.
>
> So now run this on the client:
>
> ```
> killall synergyc; sleep 1; synergyc --yscroll <lowest delta> <ip of server>
> ```
>
> Literal example:
>
> ```
> killall synergyc; sleep 1; synergyc --yscroll 28 10.0.0.1
> ```
>
> Make sure to go through any session files or setting you created to
>   include your new yscroll function.
>
> And don't use 0 or 1 (unless your delta is 1). 0 created some odd
>   issues. You want to set yscroll to your lowest possible literal delta.
>   0 or 1 neither accurate nor efficient.

Comment: +1 Also, (on a Mac host at least), the Scroll Speed system preference allows some adjustment to the scroll delta.

Comment: How do i accomplish this on a windows client? putting those messages into cmd prompt gives me errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

These steps should help. On your mac

- Go to System Preferences > Mouse
- Change scroll speed to lowest
- Restart Synergy server on your mac (you may test even before restarting server. Worked for me without a restart)
- Voilla!! Scroll should be working on both linux and mac.

Now you can go back and adjust the speed of the scroll using the same steps and test it.

Comment: I did find it was to do with scroll speed but the option isn't (or no longer is) found in System Preferences -> Mouse, it's in Accessibility -> Mouse and Trackpad.

Comment: 3yrs later and this saved me!!!

Answer (score 1):

On Mac in terminal I had to go run:
cd /Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS

Then run:
killall synergyc && sleep 10 && ./synergyc --yscroll

Example:
killall synergyc && sleep 10 && ./synergyc --yscroll 28 10.0.0.1

Comment: This looks a lot like the two-year-old answer.  What, exactly, are you saying (i.e., what, if anything, are you *adding* to the existing answer)?  Are you saying that `sleep 1` isn't enough?  Are you saying that you *need* to be in the `/Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS` directory for this to work?  Or are you just saying that you don't have that directory in your `PATH`, and so just running `synergyc` from an arbitrary directory doesn't work?  … … … … … …  In any case, showing the `./synergyc --yscroll` command without all the required parameters is confusing.

Comment: sleep 1 was not enough, also you need to be in the directory for it to work.